# How to apply custom directive for reactive forms from ts in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I am building custom  from components using rective forms by following guidlines 
given by
https://stackblitz.com/angular/ekboynmekgq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-form-question.component.html

and for validation message also i am creating one custom component,
please refer https://plnkr.co/edit/km7nGR8DjyE4l6tH5JEC?p=preview

In above second plunker link the custom directive approach is given but problem is the custom directive is directly applying to html form element not form ts

It's fine directly we can apply custom  attribute directive like this

```
 <form>
<input type="text" customDirective>
</from>
```

Now I want to build the form using custon input components
the structure looks like

```
<form>
<custom-input></cutom-input>
<custom-dropdown></custom-dropdown>
</form>
```

One thing I did n't undersood, how to apply attribute directive from ts that shoud be frendly with custom errors componet(2 nd plun link)

please any one have an idea please help me

Comment: you should be creating a custom validator

Comment: in above example 2 nd plunk link also provide custom validator approach, please check it, problem is with that it can be applying only with direct html tag

Answer (score 0):

This Medium Link - https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73 by `tarik` might give you a better idea of how to do it .

The validator Component

```
import { Component, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl, Validator } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'json-input',
    template:
        `
        <textarea
          [value]="jsonString" 
          (change)="onChange($event)" 
          (keyup)="onChange($event)">

        </textarea>
        `,
    providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => JsonInputComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => JsonInputComponent),
      multi: true,
    }]        
})
export class JsonInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
    private jsonString: string;
    private parseError: boolean;
    private data: any;

    // this is the initial value set to the component
    public writeValue(obj: any) {
        if (obj) {
            this.data = obj;
            // this will format it with 4 character spacing
            this.jsonString = JSON.stringify(this.data, undefined, 4); 
        }
    }

    // registers 'fn' that will be fired wheb changes are made
    // this is how we emit the changes back to the form
    public registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    // validates the form, returns null when valid else the validation object
    // in this case we're checking if the json parsing has passed or failed from the onChange method
    public validate(c: FormControl) {
        return (!this.parseError) ? null : {
            jsonParseError: {
                valid: false,
            },
        };
    }

    // not used, used for touch input
    public registerOnTouched() { }

    // change events from the textarea
    private onChange(event) {

        // get value from text area
        let newValue = event.target.value;

        try {
            // parse it to json
            this.data = JSON.parse(newValue);
            this.parseError = false;
        } catch (ex) {
            // set parse error if it fails
            this.parseError = true;
        }

        // update the form
        this.propagateChange(this.data);
    }

    // the method set in registerOnChange to emit changes back to the form
    private propagateChange = (_: any) => { };
}
```